# What does o << {a: a, b: b}; do?

Tags: javascript

In [Bitwise versus Assoc Array iteration](http://jsperf.com/bitwise-versus-assoc-array-iteration/2) test there is the following snippet:

```
var arr = [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1];
var o = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    var a = [(Math.random > 0.5 ? 0 : 1), (Math.random > 0.5 ? 0 : 1), (Math.random > 0.5 ? 0 : 1), (Math.random > 0.5 ? 0 : 1), (Math.random > 0.5 ? 0 : 1), (Math.random > 0.5 ? 0 : 1), (Math.random > 0.5 ? 0 : 1), (Math.random > 0.5 ? 0 : 1), (Math.random > 0.5 ? 0 : 1), (Math.random > 0.5 ? 0 : 1), (Math.random > 0.5 ? 0 : 1), (Math.random > 0.5 ? 0 : 1), (Math.random > 0.5 ? 0 : 1)];
    var b = 0;
    for(var j=0; j < a.length; j++){
            b |= (a[j] << j);               
    }
    o << {a: a, b: b};
}
```

It prepares data for testing purposes. The last statement doesn't make sense to me, except the fact that there's a left shift in it. The interpreter does not throw an error, it just accepts it silently.

Comment: read this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 4):

It makes me cry a little. There is **no operator `<<` defined over an Array**; it is *only* a bit-wise left shift in JavaScript. (Although *different* languages, like Ruby, do define such an operator on an Array type.)

It is thus *roughly* equivalent to (internally both operands are converted via the native `ToInt32` function):

```
parseInt(o) << parseInt({a: a, b: b})
```

Some warning flags should be going off:

- What is the [meaningful] result of `parseInt` (or `ToInt32`) here?
- Where does the result of `<<` go?

---

Compare with this simplified code:

```
var o = []
o << 1
o            // -> []
o.push(2)    // (as suggested by 6502 as the desired operation)
o            // -> [2]
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the **desired** meaning is `o.push({a:a, b:b})`.

I don't know if this works for some broken implementation, but it's not standard.

Comment: Since the snippet prepares o array for further processing in a loop  it looks to be true.

Comment: Later on the o array is processed like this: ...  var x = o[i], _m = x.b, k = **x & _m** > 0; (same 'meaningles' code)